# Show that $f$ is zero homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $n, m \in N^*$ and a group homomorphism $f: Z_n \to Z_m$. Show that $f(Z_n) =0$ if and only if $(n, m)=1$.

Comment: What have you done so far for this question?

Comment: We known that $Z_n. Z_m$ is cyclic if and only if $(n,m)=1$. But I don't use this to solve the problem.